# SPSS Copy Values from One Column to Another

Tags: spss

I have the following data, all variables are scale:

| S_1 | S_2 | S_3 | Results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 6 |  |  | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 0 | -4 | 6 | 0 |
|  |  | 3 | 3 |

How would I write a script in SPSS (also where would I write the script - would it be in 'compute variable'?) for each row, it would copy the fist data value it encounters and copy in Results.  If there are any null values before a value, it would skip that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a syntax window and put this there:

```
compute results=$sysmis.
   do repeat vr=S_1 S_2 S_3.
if missing(results) results=vr.
end repeat.
execute.
```

This code runs over the three variables and copies their contents into the "results" variable - while it is still empty. Once a value has been copied into it, the syntax will stop copying other values into it.

Comment: Very nice thanks.  I'm working on my larger data set, and the first row and last row for what ever reason it likes to give the last column's value.  Other than that, seems like it does all the in-between rows.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind.  If there is a condition - let's say it finds a value that shouldn't be copied but the next value should be copied.  What would you recommend?  Some IF Then statement? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you again eli-k.  I'll look into (3).  As for (2), I'm good.  I appreciate your help.